# Get ID of custom field [Salesforce]

Tags: salesforce

When using Salesforce's [SObject Describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_describe.htm) endpoint, I see a ton of metadata about an object's fields. But the property that is missing for every field is its ID.

I want to be able to track when a custom field has been changed, including when it has been renamed. So, using the field's `name` attribute won't suffice. I need some kind of unique identifier.

Naturally, I can see the ID of a custom field in the URL bar when editing the field:

```
https://my-org.lightning.force.com/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/Contact/FieldsAndRelationships/{{FIELD_ID}}/view
```

Is there a way to access this ID programmatically via the API in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> track when a custom field has been changed

You can query [SetupAuditTrail](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_setupaudittrail.htm). And when accessing SF via API - there's magic "[If Modified Since](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/describe_global_with_ifmodified_header.htm)" header (but read this too: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/186494/799)

> Is there a way to access this ID programmatically via the API

[FieldDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm) is pretty good, I've made few answers about it here.

```
SELECT DurableId, EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName, QualifiedApiName, DataType
FROM FieldDefinition
WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName IN ('Account', 'Contact', 'myNamespace__myCustomObject__c')
```

works in normal queries (incl apex) and Tooling API.